# How to correctly pass subprocess arguments

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, concatenation

I'm trying to automate concatenating a folder of (correctly formatted) mp4 video files.

(This edited version of my question reduces the problem to its lowest level of my confusion. The original title asked about the differences between `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.run` but it turns out the problem was elsewhere.)

Why does

```
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i movie1.mp4 -i movie2.mp4 -i credits.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"  \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" "output.mp4"',shell=True)
```

work fine (where `s` is a string of inputs, and `count` is the number of inputs), but

```
#python3 
#makeFinalExample.py

import subprocess

s = '-i movie1.mp4 -i movie2.mp4 -i credits.mp4'
count = 3
print(f's prints out as: {s}')


commandList = ['ffmpeg',
                '-hide_banner',
                '-loglevel',
                'error',
                #str(s),
                '{0}'.format(s),
                '-filter_complex',
                "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n={0}:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]".format(count),
                '-map',
                "[outv]",
                '-map',
                "[outa]",
                "output.mp4"]
print(f'the command list prints out as {commandList}')
subprocess.run(commandList)
```

gets the error (whether the string is delivered as `str(s)`, or in the formatting shown...

```
Unrecognized option 'i movie1.mp4 -i movie2.mp4 -i credits.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Here is a printout of the input string

```
-i movie1.mp4 -i movie2.mp4 -i credits.mp4
```

And here is a printout of the commandList

```
['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i movie1.mp4 -i movie2.mp4 -i credits.mp4', '-filter_complex', '[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]', '-map', '[outv]', '-map', '[outa]', 'output.mp4']
```

Comment: The difference here is between `shell=True` and the formatting used when you don't have that keyword argument. `subprocess.run` is basically a replacement for `subprocess.call` but it doesn't differ in this particular aspect. (They differ in what they return; `call` simply returns the status code, while `run` returns a `CompletedProcess` object which includes the status code as an attribute, but also various other pieces of information about the process you ran.)

Comment: Your translation seems competent (except `'{0}'.format(s)` is a clumsy way to write `str(s)` or simply `s` if the variable is already a string); I don't think this error is reproducible.

Comment: Please edit your post, and add the value of `s`. Please make sure that your code sample is executable, and that the error message is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for (finally) providing a [mre]. I think you can see why we require it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing with `subprocess.call` vs `subprocess.run` to do, the difference is that you are using `shell=True` in the first case, and in the second case not. The two functions behave exactly the same in this, and almost every other regard (`subprocess.run` is a newer function which supports many, many more options and returns a more useful object, but in its most basic form, it performs exactly the same job, using the same API).

The problem is that you need to split the string `s` into tokens just like you are splitting all the other command-line arguments (and the error message actually reveals this, but I suppose you have to know what to look for in order to catch it).  When you omit `shell=True` each option needs to be a separate list item, like

```
[ ..., '-i', 'movie1.mp4', '-i', 'movie2.mp4', '-i', 'credits.mp4', ...]
```

The function `shlex.split()` can help you correctly split a command into tokens:

```
commandList = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-hide_banner',
    '-loglevel', 'error',
    *shlex.split(s),
    '-filter_complex',
    "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n={0}:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]".format(count),
    '-map', "[outv]",
    '-map', "[outa]",
    "output.mp4"]
```

but a much better design for your function is probably to allow the user to pass in just a list of input video file names, and take it from there. (Then I guess `count` will not need to be specified explicitly either; it's just the value of `len(inputfilenames)`.)