Want to execute a command having python program and arguments in python
abc = "/a/b/pythonprogam.py --expr '((max(max_over_time(node_load15{job=\"acb\"}[2d])) by(data) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode=\"DEV\" }) by(data) ) * 100)' --fields data::50"
args = abc.split()
subprocess.run(args)

I want to execute the above command in Python. I tried and it's not working, throwing an error:

Invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 37: unterminated quoted string


You should not use split this way as it will split at every space... This is why it complains for a non terminating quoted string... [2d])) by( is splitted...

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70493595

If you want to run a shell command with subprocess, you have to pass shell=True and the entire command as one string.
abc = "/a/b/pythonprogam.py --expr '((max(max_over_time(node_load15{job=\"acb\"}[2d])) by(data) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode=\"DEV\" }) by(data) ) * 100)' --fields data::50"
subprocess.run(abc, shell=True)

If you want to run a program directly, without the shell and with arguments that correspond directly to Python strings, you don’t use shell syntax like quoting.
abc = [
    "/a/b/pythonprogam.py",
    "--expr", "((max(max_over_time(node_load15{job=\"acb\"}[2d])) by(data) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode=\"DEV\" }) by(data) ) * 100)",
    "--fields", "data::50",
]
subprocess.run(abc)

